# Ubuntu-SDK Plugin Loader Errors: Could not resolve dependency 'Core(2.7.1)' Could not resolve dependency 'ProjectExplorer(2.7.1)'

Tags: ubuntu-sdk, qt-creator

(In Ubuntu 13.10) Ubuntu-SDK opens with the following errors:

[image]

Does anyone know how to resolve these dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had had the same problem, but I solved it removing all the extras repositories that I had added to install `ubuntu-sdk` and removing my previus version of `qt-creator` and all the others stuff that I had installed trying to solve this problem.

After get the results of the commands:

```
apt-cache search ubuntu-sdk
```

and

```
dpkg -l | grep ubuntu-sdk
```

equals to zero.

I added the ppa repository and install the ubuntu SDK again:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk
```

After that the ubuntu SDK started to work ok for me.